# Collapse Toolbar affects other layout

Tags: duplicates, height, toolbar

I have this layout:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="center_vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:titleMarginStart="35dp"
                />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/go_to_deezer_btn"
                    android:layout_width="135dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_button"
                    android:text="@string/go_to_deezer"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_anchor="@id/header"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <com.cmd.cienradios.ui.header.EntityHeaderAlbum
                        android:id="@+id/header"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/deezer_banner"
                        layout="@layout/deezer_banner"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="70dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout_generic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
            >

            <com.cmd.cienradios.ui.TrackRecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/tracks_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

when I run the program, it collapses just fine, expected behaviour.
but there seems to be another layout added between the collapsed toolbar and my Swiperefresh layout, it's as tall as the toolbar, but empty and unreactive

Somehow the toolbar is related to this issue as the hight of this phantom layout changes when I change the height of the toolbar

the space im refering to is the one on top of the recyclerView on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly, this was fixed by moving the toolbar below the FrameLayout, when I moved it back up to reproduce the bug, it didn't do it. So I guess the lesson is "Sometimes you just have to move your code around" I guess maybe restarting the computer or shutting down Android Studio could have done the trick as well.